# Android getResource() undefined error

Tags: android

I want to draw bitmap on draw method in MyPositionOverlay extends Overlay  class but I get this error: The method getResource() is undefined for the type MyPositionOverlay

Where I'm wrong?

Here is code form draw method:

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResource(), R.drawable.icon); 
     canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The getResources() method is not a member of the Overlay class.  getResources() is a member of the Context class.  You need to pass a reference of a Context to your Overlay subclass so that it can load the Drawable resource:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

You also don't want to load a bitmap in your draw method as it is very memory intensive and will slow down your application, you should save a member variable of the bitmap in the constructor of the overlay so that it only gets loaded once.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply , but now I get this error "context cannot be resolved"

Comment: you must define Context context;

Answer (score 1):

use

```
   Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

or

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```